# Haskell: How to use random integer from randomRIO in a function that returns a boolean

Tags: haskell, random

I am new to Haskell and i'm having a problem with using the IO Int from randomRIO function. My goal is to get a random Int value, say r, and to return True if r < x or false otherwise, but i don't know how to do it.

my function should look like:

```
randomCompare :: Int->Bool

randomCompare x

  | x < r = True -- somehow i want to r <- randomRIO(start,end) 

  | otherwise = False
```

I know there is a designed intention with keeping IO vals in context for purity etc.. but i don't see why using a random number for a Boolean function should be "bad".

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to do it with the type `Int->Bool`, because the result of a function only depends on its inputs, and here the only input is the number. If you also pass in the random number then you have `randomCompare x r = x < r`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import System.Random(randomIO)

randomCompare :: Int -> IO Bool
randomCompare x = do
  r <- randomIO
  return $ x < r
```

IO is neither good nor bad, it just declares that your function has side effects. Here the side effect is modifying the state of the global random number generator, so that a subsequent call to randomIO will give another number (it wouldn't be random if it was constant !).

IO does force all calling functions to be IO too (the ones that want to use the IO Bool). However, if a calling function is IO only by consuming this IO Bool, if it has no other side effects, then you can separate it as a pure function `f :: Bool -> SomeType` and functorially apply it on the IO, ie

```
f <$> randomCompare i
```

So the IO monad only costs you to replace the ordinary function call `$` by the functorial `fmap`, also noted `<$>`. Is it so much longer to type ?

If you absolutely want to leave the IO monad (why ?), you can also draw all the random values you need first, store them in a list, then apply pure functions on that list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So i understand that there is no elegant way out of this without IO.
nevertheless, the function that is calling "randomCompare" wants just the Bool value, so hot should the calling function handle IO Bool instead of Bool?
Thanks.

Comment: If you import Control.Monad.Random and are using the MonadRandom package, you can replace `Int -> IO Bool` by `MonadRandom m => Int -> m Bool`. You can then still use that as if it was `Int -> IO Bool`, but you have the type-level gurantee that the function doesn't have any other side effect than generating random numbers.

Comment: Infinite lists of randoms are also common.  `randomCompare :: RandList -> Int -> (Bool,RandList)` where `type RandList = [Int]` and `randomCompare (x:xs) i = (i < x, xs)`.  This alternative is just leaning on lazyness instead of manually stepping some RNG and manually plumbing the data instead of hiding behind a monad (IO or MonadRandom m).

Comment: I would do the infinite list solution if my ranges weren't variable and i don't think making a list every time is the best way, so i guess i'll try to  work with the IO monad and see how it goes.  thanks guys!